# Spring security and Swagger

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger

I'm working with **Spring Boot 1.5.7**, I'm using Swagger for API documentation.
Below my security configuration:

```
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 public void configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/public/**,/api/v2/api-docs", "/api/configuration/ui", "/api/swagger-resources", "/api/configuration/security", "/api/swagger-ui.html", "/api/webjars/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.antMatcher("/api/**").addFilter(new JwtClaimFilter(authenticationManager()));
   }
}
```

I want that API with resources names:

- `api/**` are protect with JWT token (it handled from JwtClaimFilter class);
- `api/public/**` are public resources
- `api/swagger-ui.html` is a public html page.

The configuration doesn't work for `api/public/**` and the body of `swagger.ui.html` is blank, there are only footer and header. If I use ModHeader and I pass header with jwt the page works correctly.

Can you help me, please? Thanks.

Comment: Since you are adding api/** as protected with JWT token, your other configurations are overridden . Trying changing the order and configure it within the same method.

Comment: If I set only  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/public/**") it works. With swagger I have some problems

Comment: That's because, Spring Security filter chain follows some pattern execution. Spring docs says : The Spring Security filter contains a list of filter chains, and dispatches a request to the first chain that matches it. The picture below shows the dispatch happening based on matching the request path (/foo/** matches before /**). This is very common but not the only way to match a request. The most important feature of this dispatch process is that only one chain ever handles a request.      Refer this for more details https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/